# Can I return a data producer from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Suppose I have a class similar to this one (with all the necessary WCF attributes):

```
class JobProducer
{
    Job Produce()
    { 
        // Do some work
        return new Job(params);
    }
}
```

and a WCF service (I'm not writing all the attributes, but they're there)

```
   class MyService : IService
    {
        Producer GetProducer()
        {
            return new Producer();
        }    
    }
```

and a WCF client:

```
IService client;
var producer = client.GetProducer();
var job = producer.Produce();
while (job != null)
{
    // Process job
    job = producer.Produce();
}
```

Will that kind of design work? are there any drawbacks that I should be aware of?

More specifically, what happens when I invoke the `Produce()` method on the `Producer`? will WCF route that method invocation to the service and unblock the client thread when the `Job` is ready?

I thought about simply returning a `Stream` from the service, but I'd like to avoid deserializing the bytes to a concrete class and let the framework do that for me.

Comment: WCF deals with mere serialization. You send properties over the wire, not instances. You're looking for "remoting", or controlling an object living on some server from a client.

Comment: @CodeCaster Does that mean that I can't invoke a method on something that WCF returns?

Comment: You can't, because generated classes don't have methods. If you share the DTO definitions between service and client you can, but the code will run on the client.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. Does that mean that Streams are a special case supported by the framework? since I've seen examples of WCF services returning a Stream and of clients doing `Read()` on that object

Comment: Yes, [streams have special support in WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Produce() method on the local instance of the Job class will be executed. Since Produce() is not a Service Endpoint, no server calls will be made. The instance of Job returned from the Service Endpoint is not leased from the server but completely independent, and importantly, not the same Type as that on the Server but a serialization compatible Type.

Comment: Thanks. Using that logic, how come returning a Stream from a service works? I've seen examples where the client gets a Stream from the service and does `Read()` on it

Comment: Thats because its a Stream. Standard WCF classes are instances and cannot be partially deserialized from a server. Streams are designed for partial deserialization. If you are using Async server patterns you can even do the same for IEnumerable<myClass> and get it to yield up the first item in the enumerable before its all been prepared by the server - until the entire Enumerable is parsed a connection between client and server persists.